# How to return JSON in Laravel AuthServiceProvider?

Tags: json, laravel

I'm checking for a token in the `boot()` method and catching Invalid Tokens. How can I return some response in the case of an invalid token?

Here's my code:

```
public function boot(Authenticator $authenticator)
{
        Auth::viaRequest('auth-token', function ($request) use ($authenticator) {
            $bearerToken = $request->bearerToken();

            if ($bearerToken) {
                try {
                    return $authenticator->getUser($bearerToken);
                } catch (InvalidTokenException $exeception) {
                    return response()->json(['token_invalid'], 400);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

And it pips me the error:

> Method Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::getAuthIdentifier does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#closure-request-guards):

> The second argument passed to the method should be a Closure that receives the incoming HTTP request and returns a **user instance** or, if authentication fails, **null**

So instead of returning a response object, return null:

```
if ($bearerToken) {
    try {
        return $authenticator->getUser($bearerToken);
    } catch (InvalidTokenException $exeception) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, trying that I'm getting `Route [login] not defined.`, looks like Laravel is trying to redirect to a Login route. This is an API I'm building so I don't want to redirect, just a JSON response.

Comment: Ok, so now that your custom guard is working correctly, you'll need to overwrite the logic for handling unauthenticated requests. See [Protecting Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#protecting-routes)

Comment: DONE: Had to add an `unauthenticated()` function in the Laravel `Handler.php` file which returns JSON, and then add the header `Accepts: application/json` to my REST client.

Thanks for your help Drifter.